# Ruby conditional not triggering inside of reduce method

Tags: ruby

I've been staring at this for a long time and im not sure why my conditional is not triggering. I've stripped out everything and just left it down to the two conditionals and the output. For some reason its returning an entire array of wins / losses for all the data (510 in length), and not **just the wins/losses for that matching team.**

```
  def self.average_win_percentage(team_id)
    results = @@game_data.reduce([]) do |accum, game|
      if game.home_team_id == team_id
        game.home_goals > game.away_goals ? accum << "win" : accum << "loss"
      end
      if game.away_team_id == team_id
        game.away_goals > game.home_goals ? accum << "win" : accum << "loss"
      end
      accum
    end
    results
  end
```

Any idea why its not triggering? I feel like its something really obvious but I'm simply not seeing it currently.

Each element in @@game_data looks like this. Since its being parsed from a csv, ill just share one element.

```
 @away_goals=2,
 @away_team_id="3",
 @date_time="5/16/13",
 @game_id="2012030221",
 @home_goals=3,
 @home_team_id="6",
 @season="20122013",
 @type="Postseason",
 @venue="Toyota Stadium",
 @venue_link="/api/v1/venues/null"
```

The team_id being pass in as an argument is also a string type

Comment: Does `game.home_team_id == team_id` or `game.away_team_id == team_id` return true at least once?

Comment: yes, they are returning "win" / "loss" accordingly

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your snippet needs to be runnable and demonstrate the problem you're describing. Without that we have to create all the supporting data and code to make it work which defeats the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely the return value of one of your methods is not what you are expecting. You can see from an example without your methods it is properly working. You'd have to provide the original data to be more useful.

Use `binding.pry` and `require 'pry'` at top to set a breakpoint. Then inspect the return values. Perhaps one ID is a string and the other is an integer or something like that.

```
results = [1,2,3].reduce([]) do |accum, game|
  puts game
  if true
    1 > 0 ? accum << "win" : accum << "loss" 
  end
  if true
    1 > 0 ? accum << "win" : accum << "loss"
  end
  accum
end

results

#=> ["win", "win", "win", "win", "win", "win"]

require 'pry'
results = [1,2,3].reduce([]) do |accum, game|
  puts game
  if true
    0 > 1 ? accum << "win" : accum << "loss" 
  end
  if false
    1 > 0 ? accum << "win" : accum << "loss"
  end
  accum
end

results

#=> ["loss", "loss", "loss"]
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been working through the pry and it's not really revealing anything. I updated my question to include the shape of the elements in the array.

Comment: Have you checked the data type of the `home_goals`? Are you sure its actually an integer? If you compare 2 strings it can always return true in cases: `'2' > '1'` instead of `2 > 1`

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a `'6'` as a string as the argument of the function, and not `6`?

Comment: Yeah, the data i shared above is a copy/paste from the pry response for `game`. The goals are ints and the team_ids are strings. Plus the arg is also a string of "6" in this case

Comment: More than likely it's something silly that you're not seeing then. Perhaps restart console, make sure you dont have multiple things running, make sure the file is actually saving or you dont have 3 versions of the file open blah blah blah. If you try my example, does it return the proper output with the version of ruby you're using? I suspect version of ruby wouldn't matter (with the ternary) but wouldn't hurt to check.

Comment: I notice you're using a class variable and not an instance variable (which would much be preferred). Are you sure the class variable is not being manipulated somehow from another thread?

Comment: It shouldnt be, working off of pry it's the same input data coming in as expected from my csv parsing. Simply instances of `Game`. So, everything is behaving as expected.. of course, except for this method. I'll keep looking at it, maybe take a break for a bit and then come back. I'm worried it may be something super obvious but we'll see

Comment: it's most definitely something 'obvious' but we can't help you find it because you don't provide working input data. More than likely its a forehead slapper. Make sure its actually returning the wrong output (and not for instance, a long string of 'wins' when you thought there were more losses)